# SHFileOperation/SHFILEOPSTRUCT

Tags: c++, windows

Im trying to copy a directory to a new location. So I am using SHFileOperation/SHFILEOPSTRUCT as follows:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf;
memset(&sf,0,sizeof(sf));
sf.hwnd = 0;
sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;
dirName += "\\*.*";
sf.pFrom = dirName.c_str();
string copyDir = homeDir + "\\CopyDir";
sf.pTo = copyDir.c_str();
sf.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI;

int n = SHFileOperation(&sf);
if(n != 0)
{
    int x = 0;
}
```

So I set the values as above. There is a file I created in the folder (I have closed the Handle so it should be fine to move). The SHFileOperation call is returning 2, but I cant find anywhere where these error codes are explained. Does anyone know where I can find out what 2 means, or does anyone have any ideas why it might not be working? Cheers

Comment: SHFileOperation function has been replaced in Windows Vista by IFileOperation. So is it smart to use SHFileOperation? Or does the code only run on < vista. Edit: Removed a part, I misread a part of your question.

Comment: yeah ive used CopyFile But i want to move a directory with all the files and I know SHFileOperation can do that with just the code above (or, you know, with a working version of the code above). I did not know about IFileOperation. Im curious though. If im in windows explorer and i chose to copy a folder to somewhere else using keyboard/mouse does it use this IFileOperation or SHFileOperation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Error code 2 means *The system cannot find the file specified.*

See [Windows System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for full listing of error descriptions, or write a function that will obtain the description for the error code:

```
std::string error_to_string(const DWORD a_error_code)
{
    // Get the last windows error message.
    char msg_buf[1025] = { 0 };

    // Get the error message for our os code.
    if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 
                      0,
                      a_error_code,
                      0,
                      msg_buf,
                      sizeof(msg_buf) - 1,
                      0))
    {
        // Remove trailing newline character.
        char* nl_ptr = 0;
        if (0 != (nl_ptr = strchr(msg_buf, '\n')))
        {
            *nl_ptr = '\0';
        }
        if (0 != (nl_ptr = strchr(msg_buf, '\r')))
        {
            *nl_ptr = '\0';
        }

        return std::string(msg_buf);
    }

    return std::string("Failed to get error message");
}
```

From reading the documentation for [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the strings specified for `pTo` and `pFrom` must be double null terminated: yours are only singly null terminated. Try the following:

```
dirName.append(1, '\0');
sf.pFrom = dirName.c_str();
string copyDir = homeDir + "\\CopyDir";
copyDir.append(1, '\0');
sf.pTo = copyDir.c_str();
```

Comment: double null terminated. So I add a \0 to the end of each?

Comment: Its not making any difference. Im still getting 2 from SHFileOperation. Both folders exist and there is a file in the pFrom folder, so I dont know what file it cant find.

Comment: How did you append the additional NULL terminator?

Comment: I now have  dirName += "\\*.*\0", same appendage for copyDir

Comment: That won't work, as the assignment to `dirName` will stop at first NULL terminator. Try the approach I added to the answer above.

Comment: Yeah cheers that worked. Thanks a lot for this. I am curious why it works with append? How is that different to just adding it to the string?

Comment: [`append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) does not depend on the presence of the null terminator. As this worked you can accept the answer if you want to. ;)