# System Error 124 - ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL with SHFileOperation

Tags: c++, windows

I was having a problem with using `SHFileOperation`: [SHFileOperation/SHFILEOPSTRUCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191415/shfileoperation-shfileopstruct). I got that working but I am now trying to put that into a function as it will be used several times throughout my code. The functions is:

```
void SHFileOperationFunc(string item1, string item2, int operation)
{
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf;
    memset(&sf,0,sizeof(sf));
    sf.hwnd = 0;
    sf.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI;

    switch(operation)
    {
    case 1:

    case 2:
        sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;
        string files = item1 + "\\*.*";
        files.append(1, '\0');
        sf.pFrom = files.c_str();
        item2.append(1, '\0');
        sf.pTo = item2.c_str();
    }

    int opOkay = SHFileOperation(&sf);
    if(opOkay != 0)
    {
        //FAIL
    }
```

}

When I had the code outside the function it worked fine. But now that it is as above i get an error returned to opOkay. The error value is 124 which means ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL - The system call level is not correct. I dont know what this means. Google hasnt been much help either. Anyone enlighten me?

Also should i be using `SHFileOperation` at all or should I be using `IFileOperation`?

Cheers.

Comment: Error code 124 = 0x7c = [`DE_INVALIDFILES` (The path in the source or destination or both was invalid)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen, that was the confuse for me. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `files` will go out of scope when the switch block ends and `sf.pFrom` will be a dangling pointer. Move declaration of `files` to outside of the `switch`.

*Note you have no `break`s in either of the `switch` blocks.*

Comment: soooo should have seen that one. Thanks